# Use Mac as wireless router, and send wireless traffic through proxy

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, proxy, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a Mac as a wireless router, and run all wireless traffic through a proxy/VPN?](https://superuser.com/questions/167888/using-a-mac-as-a-wireless-router-and-run-all-wireless-traffic-through-a-proxy-vp)

Hi,

I am looking to use Mac OS X as a wireless router, using Internet Sharing, so I can wirelessly connect my Android 2.1 (rooted) phone. However, I would like all of my wireless traffic to be routed through a proxy. So, local Mac traffic cannot be run through the proxy, only the wireless traffic.

I already have Internet Sharing enabled, and I can access the internet on the Android, but it is not being routed through the proxy. I have specified a proxy by clicking Ethernet > Advanced > Proxies. I placed my proxy ip and port in the "Web Proxy", "Secure Web Proxy", and "SOCKS proxy", and I still cannot connect through the proxy via the Android, and I can no longer load pages in Safari, until I uncheck the proxies. Should I be adding the proxy in the AirPort > Advanced > Proxies section? Also, does the service order make any difference?

Please note, the Android does not appear to have a method of adding a proxy for the device itself.

Another note, I am inexperienced when it comes to Macs, so detailed instructions would be preferred.

Comment: You asked this question before: http://superuser.com/questions/167888/using-a-mac-as-a-wireless-router-and-run-all-wireless-traffic-through-a-proxy-vp/167913#167913 and I answered it there.

Comment: I merged your both accounts, since the previous question was asked as an unregistered user, this is probably why you couldn't find it back. They are now both associated to the same account, I'm closing this new question as a duplicate of the previous one. Enjoy your stay on Super User.